# 3-cycle enumeration on random dot product graph

Tags: random-graphs

The graph is generated with $p=n^{-0.5}$,which $p$ means the probability the two random vector dot product is large enough to add an edge. Brute force algorithm run in expect time $O(n^2)$.I think the expect number of 3-cycles are O(n).Is there an algorithm run in expect time in $O(m)$ or at least  better than brute force?

Comment: Unless you're looking for an expected rather than worst-case time, the random graph model will not matter. (But do you mean random *dot product* graph?) What will matter is the input format; e.g. if the graph is given as an adjacency matrix, then obviously we cannot do better than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, my meaning just as you says.

Answer (score 1):

Finally , i get an negative result. This paper [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09318) shows that need at least $O(m^{4/3})$ time for a exact algorithm under ASPS hypothesis which is as bad as brute force.

[Monochromatic Triangles, Triangle Listing and APSP](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09318)